# std::array vs classic array[].. How does that work?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, c++11, stdarray

I keep reading on this amazing new `std::array` feature that came with C++11. It appears that `std::array<int, 4> a;` is.. as light as `int a[4];` in terms of memory, and that it is.. *as fast* in terms of reading and writing, *more safe* as far as memory management is concerned.. and you can even *iterate* on it.. and use nice *initializers*..

I can't help thinking "Yeah but.. where's the snag?". How the heck does that work? What is this `std::array<int,4> a` object? Where is the cost of having so many new features? Is it just *sweat* from the C++ creators? Is it more weight in the language implementation? More work for the compiler? How can it be so wonderful? Am I just missing something?

How can all these features be added to a classical array with no cost at runtime? The answer seems to be that the *compiling effort* does the trick, and `std::array` is no more a miracle to me.. just a delight.

Comment: That "something big" you mean is member functions. Plain member functions in a template class that may use the length of the array as a constant expression.

Comment: You sound like a C person that wrote his/her first C++ program. The answer is, more or less, *the compilers exist*.

Comment: What's so surprising about it? Even a simple homebrew class that wraps an `int[]` and knows its length as a compile-time constant will exhibit these attributes.

Comment: `std::array` was first introduced with the TR1. It allows a standard container "interface" wrapper over an aggregate type for traditional arrays. So basically all the standard algorithms and techniques can be applied to arrays.

Comment: Too many questions! Ask one single, clear question.

Comment: the question is unclear, voted to close

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Haha! Wrong, I came the opposite way from high-level scripting langages. But C++ provides a great opportunity for *deconstructing* everything, doesn't it?

Comment: Just to give it a bit of justice - ordinary arrays have just about all of that except bound checking. Pointer *is* an iterator.

Comment: @juanchopanza, let's say we'll use this post to gather information on the topic. I could hardly find anything about it but "How to use it"s..

Comment: @keltar Ordinary arrays cannot be copied or assigned.

Comment: @juanchopanza and I'm sure a lot more differences could be found. But it wasn't stated in question.

Comment: @Jon And does this also have a cost? In terms of *compiling effort* maybe?

Comment: @Iago-lito: Of course it does. *Everything* has a cost in terms of compiling effort, otherwise compilation would take "zero" seconds for any program.

Comment: @Jon: Very true! ^ ^ But is it that only "compiling effort cost" that makes `std::array` so useful for.. *no cost at all* at runtime?

Comment: @Iago-lito: The standard demands that conforming implementations offer strict complexity guarantees for all operations on standard library containers, including `std::array`. The actual measured cost of operations vs. let's say doing the same things with an `int[]` is of course dependent both on the compiler (and its settings!) and on the implementation of the standard library. But yes, the idea behind `std::array` is that "a reasonable compiler" will produce code with zero extra runtime cost vs. a bare array.

Comment: @Iago-lito: honestly I don't get why you think it should have any cost, the point of `std::array` is mostly of better semantic (no implicit decay to pointer) and syntax sugar, all compile-time stuff. All the class has to store is a fixed-size array with size known at compile time (thus it is exactly as big as the array); the `operator[]` just forwards to the `operator[]` of the inner array, so it has no cost; the size is a compile time constant, so it is inlined; the `begin()` and `end()` can be plain pointers (with `end()` being just a fixed offset from `begin()`), so again no overhead.

Comment: @E_net4 @Jon @MatteoItalia: well, I do feel kinda better now. Your comments could actually be answers. What I missed was hidden in the actual power of *compilation* indeed. The only cost at runtime might finally be the **highly** negligible cost of storing `std::array`'s member functions' instructions. ;)

Comment: @Iago-lito: actually, `std::array`'s member functions are most likely to be inlined, so they should boil down to the same code that would be emitted if using a plain C array.